# Spring Integration JPA - Retrieving Outbound Gateway with Entity Graph

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is it possible to use entity graph in Jpa Retrieving Outbound Gateway?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow findContract() {
    return f -> f
            .handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(this.entityManagerFactory)
                    .entityClass(Contract.class)
                    //.parameterExpression("contractNumber", "payload"))
                    // set entityGraph name
            ;
}
```

I would like to use approach similar to Spring Data Jpa

```
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<Contract, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "contract.documents", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Contract findByContractNumber(String contractNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just not implemented in the Spring Integration.

Feel free to raise an appropriate [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) for such an improvement. Of course, [Contribution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc) is welcome.

Meanwhile as a workaround you can use a `@ServiceActivator` (`.handle()` in Java DSL) to call that `ContractRepository.findByContractNumber()` method.